# rails guard not working on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rspec, guard

I'm not quite a "windows lover" and I'm having some issue here with guard and the command line.

I already installed guard-rspec via bundle, but when I try to use it in CMD like this:

```
guard init rspec
```

it says guard is not recognized as an internal or external command etc. Just like when something is not on the system path.

But as I said I don't know too much about windows issues.

Does anybody know something about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have an update. In fact the problem is that I have 2 drives(C and D) and my code is on D but the ruby and guard are on C. Is a system path problem right? (I temporary fixed with absolute paths but i know there is a better solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to execute:

```
bundle exec guard
```

Comment: the guard gem is already installed. I added and update about the problem above

Comment: @RDAM I've had similar path problems on Windows before. Can you please post the absolute paths you're using to fix it?

Comment: i was wrong about your answer. I confused myself. Executing from the bundle also work. Nevertheless, the paths are: the ruby.exe path and the guard path inside the gems folder (...\gems\1.9.1\gems\guard-1.0.0\bin). Thank you.

Comment: @RDAM I'm glad you could fix it!